# Multiplying a DataFrame with duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiply a DataFrame with a Series, where the DataFrame has the exact same index as the Series, albeit with duplicate index values. The desired result is that each row in the DataFrame is multiplied by the corresponding value in the Series, based on the values of the indices.

Multiplying a Series with duplicate index values works perfectly:

```
import pandas as pd
weights = pd.Series([10, 100], [0, 1])
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 1, 1])
s.mul(weights)
```

yielding the expected result:

```
0     10
0     20
1    300
1    400
```

Multiplying a DataFrame with duplicate index values, however, produces a *ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [-1, -2, -3, -4]}, [0, 0, 1, 1])
df.mul(weights, axis=0)
...
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

How can I achieve the following result?

```
     a    b
0   10  -10
0   20  -20
1  300 -300
1  400 -400
```

**Edit:**

One option is to reindex the weights Series first:

```
df.mul(weights.reindex(df.index, method='ffill'), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `apply` method so that you multiply the data frame column by column?

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.mul(weights))

#     a    b
#0   10  -10
#0   20  -20
#1  300 -300
#1  400 -400
```